# How to do VLOOKUP in google app script with a concat value from 2 columns as the parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I just want to make a vlookup in google app script with the result of concat from 2 columns as parameter to match with a column from different spreadsheet and then take the values of the matched row. Here is the example:

**Spreadsheet 1**:

| Number | Type | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | num1 |  |  |
| 6789 | num2 |  |  |
| 12345 | num1 |  |  |

**Spreadsheet 2**:

| ID | Age | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345num1 | 22 | Andrea | New York |
| 6789num2 | 23 | Roman | California |

**CASE**: I want to concat the 2 columns (Number & Type) from spreadsheet 1 and check it if the result of the concat same as the "ID" column from spreadsheet 2, then get the values of column "Name" and "City" from spreadsheet 2 and set the value to the column of spreadsheet 1.
Note: The data in the spreadsheet 1 can be a duplicate data and dynamic.

From my code, I already made the matching methods but the problem is the set values has an error that said ***"The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1."*** and if I change the range of numColumns to 2, then it will show the error again (***the range has 2, but the data has 1***).

Is there anyone can fix this problem from my code? You guys can just make your own code as solution for the case, it can really help as well. Thanks

```
function main3() {
  var target_file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var concat = target_file.getRange(2, 1, target_file.getLastRow() - 1, target_file.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var source_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheetByName("");
  var source_data = source_file.getRange(2, 1, source_file.getLastRow() - 1, source_file.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var temp = [];
  var temp2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < concat.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = [concat[i][0] + concat[i][1]];
    temp2.push(temp[i]);
  }
  var matching = temp2.map(row => {
    var row_match = source_data.find(r => r[0] == row[0])
    return row_match ? [row_match[2], row_match[3]] : [null]
    
  })
  target_file.getRange(2, 2, matching.length, matching[0].length).setValues(matching); error
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back the edit as my answer is incomplete without the code in the question. If there's a genuine valid reason, you want to remove the code, let me know.

Comment: Its Okay. Yesterday I want to change the code to the correct one, but I forgot to change it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating unequal number of columns here:

> return row_match ? [row_match[2], row_match[3]] : [null]

If it finds a row match, the function returns two column elements per row, else it returns only one. You need a uniform array:

```
return row_match ? [row_match[2], row_match[3]] : [null, null]
```

Comment: Okay, i'll try to run it again

Comment: bruh, it works. a little mistake that take so long to realize it. Thank you for your help, dude!